# SQL Hourly Data Calculations for a date range

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQLSERVER 2012:

SQL Query to return 24 hours data where hours starts from 0-23. the query am working on is that when you select a date range say for example '1-1-2014' and 1-2-2014' the report should fetch data for hours 9am to nextday 8 am.

Query should calculate whatever date range we select, but should only pick hours from 9 am to 8 am next day/month/year.

Table Structure/columns I have is in the DB:
ReadingDate
Hours: 0-23
Data 1
Data 2
Data 3

Output

```
Date    |       Hours|         Data 1|       Data 2|     Data 3

sSelect = "Select P.ReadingDate,P.Hour,P.Data1,P.Data2,P.Data3 FROM Operations P WHERE P.ReadingDate = '" & startdate & "' AND P.Hour Between 9 AND 23 Group by P.ReadingDate,P.Hour,P.Data1,P.Data2,P.Data3
Union 
Select P.ReadingDate,P.Hour,P.Data1,P.Data2,P.Data3 FROM Operations P WHERE P.ReadingDate = '" & Enddate & " ' AND P.Hour Between 0 And 8 group by P.ReadingDate,P.Hour,P.Data1,P.Data2,P.Data3 "

2015-1-15 12:00 AM|      9| 1900|2000|300
2015-1-15 12:00 AM|     10|
2015-1-15 12:00 AM|     11|
2015-1-15 12:00 AM|     12|
2015-1-15 12:00 AM|     13|
2015-1-15 12:00 AM|     14|
2015-1-15 12:00 AM|     15|
2015-1-15 12:00 AM|     16|
2015-1-15 12:00 AM|     17|
2015-1-15 12:00 AM|     18|
2015-1-15 12:00 AM|     19|
2015-1-15 12:00 AM|     20|
2015-1-15 12:00 AM|     21|
2015-1-15 12:00 AM|     22|
2015-1-15 12:00 AM|     23|
2015-1-16 12:00 AM|      0|
2015-1-16 12:00 AM|      1|
2015-1-16 12:00 AM|      2|
2015-1-16 12:00 AM|      3|
2015-1-16 12:00 AM|      4|
2015-1-16 12:00 AM|      5|
2015-1-16 12:00 AM|      6|
2015-1-16 12:00 AM|      7|
2015-1-16 12:00 AM|      8|
```

I am able to fetch 1 day data for the date range '1-1-2015' and '1-2-2015', but if i select a date range for month '12-1-2014' to 12-31-2014' its not giving me the whole data and it again gets me the 1 day data.

Comment: Which dbms? (Date/time/interval handling is too often not according to the ANSI SQL standard.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is made with SQL Server in mind:

```
DECLARE @BeginDate datetime = '2014-01-01';     --List only as a starting date; do not include the time
DECLARE @EndDate datetime = '2014-01-02';       --List only as a end date; do not include the time; should not be the same as @BeginDate;
                                                --Could change this to expect the same date, but will need to add a full day to @EndDate below in addition to hour
SET @BeginDate = DATEADD(HOUR, 9, @BeginDate);  --Sets the starting time at 9:00 AM per business rules
SET @EndDate = DATEADD(HOUR, 8, @EndDate);      --Sets the ending time at 8:00 AM per business rules

SELECT
    YourTable.ReadingDate,
    YourTable.Hours,
    YourTable.Data1,
    YourTable.Data2,
    YourTable.Data3
FROM
    YourTable
WHERE
    DATEADD(HOUR, YourTable.Hours, YourTable.ReadingDate) BETWEEN @BeginDate AND @EndDate;
```

Comment: Richard, Thank you so much for the query. I tried and it worked as per the same. Thank you once again.

Comment: How do i set the Parameter Value in SSRS for the BeginDate and EndDate. This report is generated using SSRS. When i run the query is SQL its working just file. But when i tried to incorporate in SSRS it throws me out.

Comment: If you are inputting this SQL directly into SSRS and not using a stored procedure, add the hours (lines 4 & 5) in you WHERE statement (after BETWEEN) then add the parameters in report builder under the parameters section and make sure they are added to your dataset properties.

Comment: I set the Parameters BeginDate & StartDate with datatype Date&Time. Then on the Dataset Properties query i added the following:                                                                             SELECT
    YourTable.ReadingDate,
    YourTable.Hours,
    YourTable.Data1,
    YourTable.Data2,
    YourTable.Data3
FROM
    YourTable
WHERE
    DATEADD(HOUR, YourTable.Hours, YourTable.ReadingDate) BETWEEN DATEADD(HOUR, 9, @BeginDate) AND DATEADD(HOUR, 8, @EndDate);